# In jQuery, how do you destroy resizable() feature after your completely finish resizing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a application when you click on a div it starts a resizable function on the div, but when I click off of it, or click on another div how can i destroy it?  I don't think the `stop: function(){}` will quite do it because it will destroy it after one resize.  Any ideas?

I have an example here: http://www.fissiondesigns.com/simon/

You can click on either box on the image and resize it, but after that I want to be able to destroy the resizable feature if you click on another box, kind of like selectable boxes, but only 1 at a time.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

To remove the resizable feature from an element, use:

```
$('#my-box').resizable("destroy");
```

See http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/ for the full documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(element).resizable("destroy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the disabled property to turn off resizable()

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Documentation:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable